# how to run cleanup on snap shutdown

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I'm using [serversession-backend-acid-state](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/serversession-backend-acid-state) for sessions, along with [serversession-frontend-snap](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/serversession-frontend-snap).

If I run with the memory version of acid-state, everything works fine:

```
-- create state container in memory from initial state
acidMem :: IO (AcidStorage SessionMap)
acidMem = AcidStorage <$> openMemoryState emptyState

app :: SnapletInit App App
app = makeSnaplet "app" "An snaplet example application." Nothing $ do
  conf <- getSnapletUserConfig
  h <- nestSnaplet "" heist $ heistInit "templates"
  s <- nestSnaplet "sess"sess $ SS.simpleServerSessionManager acidDisk id
```

I can successfully use the disk version of acid-state by using the following:

```
acidDisk :: IO (AcidStorage SessionMap)
acidDisk = AcidStorage <$> openLocalState emptyState
```

My problem arises when I shut down snap; I don't know where I can properly close acid-state via `(createCheckpointAndClose . acidState)`. Without a proper shutdown, I will get an error when restarting snap.

I see the `cleanup` function in Main.hs, but I don't understand how I can use this to close acid-state. What is the best approach for this?

Edit: I've discovered `onUnload`, but can't wrap the simpleServerSessionManager with it.

Edit #2: I've determined how to use `onUnload` to get it working with acidDisk:

```
    ad <- liftIO $ fmap opts . createState =<< acidDisk
    s <- nestSnaplet "sess"sess $ 
        SS.initServerSessionManager (return ad)
    onUnload (createCheckpointAndClose $ acidState $ storage ad)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, I solved it by getting a reference to the acid-state, and then using onUnload to close it:

```
acidDisk :: IO (AcidStorage SessionMap)
acidDisk = AcidStorage <$> openLocalState emptyState

app :: SnapletInit App App
app = makeSnaplet "app" "An snaplet example application." Nothing $ do
  conf <- getSnapletUserConfig
  h <- nestSnaplet "" heist $ heistInit "templates"

  ad <- liftIO $ fmap opts . createState =<< acidDisk
  s <- nestSnaplet "sess"sess $ 
        SS.initServerSessionManager (return ad)
  onUnload (createCheckpointAndClose $ acidState $ storage ad)
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you shut down the server? If it is by killing the process, you will need to catch the `ThreadKilled` and/or `UserInterrupt` exceptions, as documented [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Exception.html)

(Snap does not appear to have an "in case of forceful shutdown" hook, nor is it really its obligation)

Otherwise, you'll have to add the checkpointing instruction as part of whatever shutdown procedure you have.

Comment: Thanks, I've figured out the solution using onUnload.